# Powershell A Drive C Does Not Exist

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

I am using a regular system, nothing virtual, my C drive is not mapped which I see in some forums. Environment path not set?

I started a tutorial to learn Powershell, and the first thing I tried to execute was very simple:

```
PS C:\Users\user> get-help get
```

Error I receive:

```
get-help : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '.C' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-help get
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.C:String) [Get-Help], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand
```

Image:
[image]

System:

Windows7, Powershell 4.0, .NET 4.5

Comment: Notice how it says `.C`. That's certainly not what a valid drive letter looks like. Did you make any changes that could have caused this?

Comment: Have you changed any of the powershell config files? For example `C:\Users\{username}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`?

Comment: @DavidPostill All I did was install the required files from the microsoft website and tried to execute this line. I did not configure anything or touch any files that were installed. Simply run(cmd) then powershell just as the image demonstrates. Nothing else.

Comment: General: What is with the down voting? Someone is on a spree of bad manners today. I checked out the question board and there are like 20 -1's in a row. Someone had too much to drink I think. Something wrong with the way I posed this question? Please do comment.

Comment: @ejbytes Did you reboot after installing? I recall mine misbehaving after installing version 4.0 (it displayed the wrong version number until I rebooted).

Comment: @DavidPostill So many rude and ignorant people out there. So eager to down vote to inflate one's own ego I think is the logical answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill Powershell was already on my PC. The error. Then I installed another version. The same. Maybe I will uninstall my .NET and uninstall powershell. I'll post later after work to state if/if not it works out.

Comment: @ejbytes Down votes are FREE and don't cost reputation on questions so you'll see this more often. In any case, I have some ideas but see if the simple stuff resolves first before I comment or add an answer. It'll likely be an answer otherwise I'll have to post a ton of comments. Start with the reboot as suggested and see if that resolves. If not, repost back and I'll keep an eye out for a response or an accepted answer, etc. before I do anything further. I don't want to polute the air too much so start with what you've been requested to do first and hopefully it is as simple as that.

Comment: @DanielB I reboot. Still no. I uninstalled .NET. Reinstalled .NET. Reinstalled Powershell. Then I was thinking about your '.C' comment. I did change my Environment Variables a couple years ago per a "fix" for JUNIT testing in Java. In a forum it stated that a '.' must be added to the JUNIT path and must be in front (the first item in Environment Variables Path). So I took out the period, restarted a new terminal session and viola! It was the '.' in the Environmental Variables on my machine. I saw the '.C' in the message but didn't really think about the '.' because so many times it's necessary

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE Thank you for watching out. I discovered a wrench in my Environment Variables Path. It really didn't seem to stick out to me because in a lot of code I write sometimes I have to put the '.' in, in order for the code to recognize a path or current directory ( e.g. "./" vs "/" )

Comment: @ejbytes No problem, I'm glad you resolved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that I had a bug in my Environment Variables, Path. Here is the screen shot of what I changed.

[image]

After trying to reboot and fail. Uninstalled .NET, reinstalled .NET, reinstalled a Powershell version and still fail. I ended up checking my Environment Variables. I had changed them a few years ago per a "fix" for JUNIT testing in Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

#### get-help : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '.C' does not exist.

Your PowerShell installation is broken or mis-configured.

It should produce output similar to the following:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> get-help get

Name                              Category  Module                    Synopsis
----                              --------  ------                    --------
Get-Verb                          Function
Get-FileHash                      Function  Microsoft.PowerShell.U... ...
Get-Command                       Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core ...
Get-Module                        Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core ...
Get-Help                          Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core ...
Get-History                       Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core ...
Get-PSSessionConfiguration        Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core ...
Get-PSSession                     Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.Core ...
...
```

Comment: I realized that this is the desired output. It's a fresh install. What would cause this error?

Comment: @ejbytes Have you changed any of the powershell config files? For example `C:\Users\{username}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Comment: No. I didn't configure anything. I am a noob for Powershell and Admin functions.